# List metadata of .wav files in commandline via powershell

Tags: powershell, metadata, powershell-2.0, wav

I would like to print a list of meta-data associated with a directory of wav files in command line as a small part of an indexing system I'm building.

Most of the project is in PHP which I'm fine with. This part requires powershell since the server with the wav files only has that on it.

I found some code online:

```
function funMetaData($folder)
{
foreach($sFolder in $folder)
 {
  $a = 0
  $objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
  $objFolder = $objShell.namespace($sFolder)

  foreach ($strFileName in $objFolder.items())
   { FunLine( "$($strFileName.name)")
     for ($a ; $a  -le 266; $a++)
      { 
        if($objFolder.getDetailsOf($strFileName, $a))
          {
            $hash += @{ `
                  $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a))  =`
                  $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($strFileName, $a)) 
                  } #end hash
           $hash
           $hash.clear()
          } #end if
      } #end for 
    $a=0
   } #end foreach
 } #end foreach
} #end funMetadata
```

This isn't mine, I've tested it, and it's close to what I want. I want to be able to print only the name of the file, the date created, date modified, and file length, I have no idea where to start breaking this down though.

Could someone please point me in the right direction and give me a couple of examples please? Please bare in mind, powershell is entirely new to me, and so far I'm finding it's syntax very 'different' in itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to clearly understand your question, But I think that you don't need all that stuff.

```
$folder = 'c:\temp\test'

foreach ($file in (get-childitem $folder))
{
  $file.FullName
  $file.name
  $file.CreationTime
  $file.LastWriteTime
  $file.Length
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming wav files will have the same type of meta information as other audio files.  I've created a blog entry where I use a 3rd party utility called taglib to extract this information for PowerShell.  Have a look to see if it fits your scripting need: [ID3 Tag Editing](http://tomorrow.uspeoples.org/2013/02/powershell-id3-tag-editing-via-taglib.html)